# Uploading file using asp.net generic handler and extjs

Tags: c#, asp.net, extjs, extjs4

I am using ExtJS to uplaod a file to server. I am using ASP.Net generic handler for it. I am able to upload the file but I am unable to get the response at the client side. At the client side it always throws an error. The description of the error is blank. Here is the code for handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".\\FileUpload");
            string uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").ToUpper().Trim();
            string fileName = context.Request.Files["UploadedFile"].FileName;
            string fileExtension = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("."));
            context.Request.Files["UploadedFile"].SaveAs(path + "\\" + uniqueFileName + fileExtension);
context.Response.Write("File uploaded");
        }
```

Below is the code I have written on the client side:

```
 uploadFile: function (button) {
            var form = button.up('form').getForm();
            if (form.isValid()) {
                form.submit({
                    url: 'http://localhost/MyApplicationName/FileHandler.ashx',
                    waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
                    success: function (response) {
                        var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
Ext.Msg.alert('Status', result);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', result);
                    }
                });
            }
    }
```

Can someone point out the error and how to make it work?

Comment: One thing i see is that you are using `Ext.decode()` however, the data written to the response is not `json`.  You should be able to just read the `responseText` directory without the decode or you need to format as `json`.

Comment: You should see errors in the console. You must get errors, as pointed out by @weeksdev.